# Oracle: why I can't select from VIEW using <SCHEMA_NAME>.<VIEW_NAME>?

Tags: oracle, select, view, schema

There are some changes on the core product on which I'm working and some tables become now views and they are not working anymore because a view cannot be referenced with the schema name in front.

For example, the below will return an error: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

```
select * from my_schema.my_view;
```

while a direct select from the view works fine

```
select * from my_view;
```

In case of a table, both scenarios above are working fine, is just the view that doesn't accept schema_name in front.

Why is that? Are there any decent workarounds?

**EDIT:** the selects are executed with my_schema user

Comment: It is possible that MY_VIEW is now a public synonym pointing to a view, while you do not have a view (or table) by the same name in your own schema. Try to figure out the reason first, before thinking about workarounds.

Comment: You can do something like this... I know I can select from V$VERSION but not from "my schema".V$VERSION. Then I can run `select * from all_objects where object_name = 'V$VERSION';` - this shows me that V$VERSION is a public synonym (not a view!)

Comment: @mathguy it cannot find my_schema.V$VERSION. Running the second select it finds the public synonym.

Comment: I hope you didn't run the statement EXACTLY as I wrote it, with `V$VERSION`. What do you get when you run it with `MY_VIEW` instead? (Assuming that is the real view name you are looking for - if not, substitute as needed!)

Comment: @mathguy I think you were right with the public synonym. **my_view is a public synonym for my_view_r**. I can query from my_schema.my_view_r.
Can I add another synonym my_schema.my_view for my_view_r?

Comment: Yes - you can create a private synonym, which will then be used if you reference it prefixed with your schema name. The public and the private synonym can have the same name, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks all for your help, especially @mathguy.

Basically the problem was that my_view was in fact a public synonym for my_view_r which was the actual view and being public, you cannot call it using the schema name in front like I was trying. eg:

```
select * from my_schema.my_view;
```

Maybe it will be helpful for others that are facing this issue in the future, the workaround would be to create a private synonym to the same view (my_view_r) using the schema name like below:

```
create synonym my_schema.my_view for my_view_r;
```

This is the only way to call a synonym using the schema name.

Answer (score 0):

It's a grant issue.

```
grant all on my_view to my_schema
```

Comment: Thanks Diego for reply. It's not a grant issue since my_view is part of my_schema and I execute the select using my_schema user.

Comment: @Alin - are you sure MY_VIEW is part of MY_SCHEMA? How do you know that? Just being albe to select from it (with no other evidence) is not conclusive. I can select from V$VERSION but I don't have a view by that name in my schema.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your schema really is the owner by running:

```
Select * from all_objects where object_name = 'my_view';
```

I have a view stvytro with owner baninst1. There is a public synonym of the same name. The following both work:

```
select * from STVYTRO;
select * from baninst1.stvytro;
```